# cannot terminate process with socket.accept

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple python proxy with Python 3.8 on Windows 10

If I use `socket.accept` I cannot terminate the process from console neither of these work: `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+z`, `ctrl+d`, `break`, `ctrl+break`, only closing the terminal.

I found in the docs this PIP https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/ that is about retrying system calls on interrupts. I believe this is the reason why I cannot terminate the app.

Can anyone tell me a best practice how to terminate an app with a blocking `socket.accept`

Thanks in advance

my code:

```py
import socket

bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))

server.listen(5)

print("[*] Listening on {}:{}".format(bind_ip, bind_port))

def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print("received: " + request.decode('ascii'))

    client_socket.send("ACK".encode('ascii'))
    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()

    print("[*] accepted {}:{}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
    handle_client(client)
```

Comment: share code which you have tried for socket.

Comment: suggestion: use `socket.settimeout()` , it will limit the time your socket will wait for incoming connections

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly to reproduce the problem? Ctrl+C _does_ terminate your code for me.

Comment: Also I’m not sure PEP 475 applies. From a cursory Google search I don’t think Windows raises EINTR. i could be wrong though.

Comment: @xrisk I am on Win10, Python 3.8.2 and trying from cmd.exe. For me it doesn't terminate :\

Comment: Can you try adding `daemon=True` to your threads?

Comment: @xrisk, if I don't connect to it execution doesn't even go to the threading part. It stops at accept() because it's blocking by default

Answer (score 0):

The socket might be in a *TIME_WAIT* state from the earlier trials & executions of your code.

You can use this flag to mitigate this, `socket.SO_REUSEADDR`

Under the [Python Socket Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#module-socket), you can set the flag like this.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

You can also look into setting a timeout for the socket!

Comment: the SO_REUSEADDR did not solve the problem. setting a timeout does make it workable. it lets the KeyboardInterrupt to be thrown.

Comment: I see, would the "setting timeout" solution be what you will be using?

Comment: I went for creating another main thread for server.accept(), this way the main thread is not blocked and can still receive interrupts!